# use of chap-password and mschap-resposse attributes

Tags: pptp, radius-protocol

With Radius I want to understand if 'chap-password' attribute can be used for authentication for both chap and mschap.
Or 'chap-password' is used for chap protocol only and 'mschap-challenge', 'mschap-response' VSA's  are used for Mschap based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Found a link which is explaining that Mschap uses Mschap  VSAs and CHAP uses CHAP-PASSWORD AVP for authentication.

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/freeradius-working-authentication-methods

Also RFC 2548 which explains Microsoft vendor-specific RADIUS attributes doesn't say that CHAP-PASSWORD can also be used for MSCHAP authentication.